# what is "struct* struct newStruct(int somedata) { } " syntax in c++

Tags: c++, elaborated-type-specifier

I was trying to make a tree in c++ and came across this code which is really confusing me.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

// The code bellow this is the part i dont understand
struct node* newNode(int idata)
{
    node* node = new struct node;
    node->data = idata;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

what is `struct node*` ? Some kind of a structure, but a pointer? Also shouldn't structs have `;` at the end? For example, `node` has `;` at the end of the body but not `node*` ?

Comment: It's C syntax. You can remove the keyword `struct` in C++.

Comment: `newNode` is a function that takes an `int` and returns a `node*` pointer. Here `struct node` is the same as `node` - the redundant `struct` keyword is a remnant of C language, almost never needed in C++. For further details, see [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

Answer (score 0):

`struct node*` is the return type of function `newNode()` and not a definition in itself. The line you are referring to is the signature of the function `newNode`. It is followed by the function definition between the two curly braces {}. A function definition does not need a `;` at the end.